# Multiple regression and hypothesis test $H_0$:$\beta_2=0$

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, self-study, regression-coefficients

Multiple regression model
$H_0$:$\beta_2=0$, $H_1$:$\beta_2 \neq 0$
where $\beta_2$ is the vector of elements ($\beta_2, \beta_3, \dots, \beta_k$) and $\beta$ is slope of regression line.

Why it is equivalent to a test based on the statistic
$$\frac{R^2/(k-1)}{(1-R^2)/(T-k)}$$
where $R^2$ is the square of the multiple correlation coefficient of the equation.

I don't know how to solve this. Please give me any suggestion or hint.

Comment: What is "$T$"?  One can make a fair guess, because the statistic looks like a ratio of statistics each of which is (a) related to a variance and (b) divided by a count: it *must* be an $F$ statistic.  That suggests you investigate situations where $F$ statistics are used and learn (if you don't already know) what hypothesis an $F$ test evaluates.